# Execute code after HTTP response is sent

Tags: servlets, httpresponse, post-processing

In a Java servlet based web application, is there any way to execute some code after and depending on the `HttpServletResponse` that has been sent to the client?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can:

- make a `Filter` that has code after the `chain.doFilter(request, response)` method
- make a filter that wraps the `HttpServletResponse` in a custom response object which handles whatever operations you like - in this case - replacing the `OutputStream` with one that logs the desired information